# Expression in QGIS print composer legend keeps reverting to expression instead of result

Tags: qgis, legend, expression

I have a number of expressions in my legend of the following type to show proportions of a total and label them as a percentage of that total, eg:

19th century ([%round(aggregate(layer:='Dwelling_Other',aggregate:='count', expression:="Cons_Yr", filter:=("Locality" IN ('Archies Creek') AND "Cons_Yr" >= 1801 AND "Cons_Yr" <= 1900))/aggregate(layer:='Dwelling_Other',aggregate:='count', expression:="Cons_Yr", filter:=("Locality" IN ('Archies Creek') AND "Cons_Yr" >= 1801))*100)%]%)

These results and labels show correctly in the legend:

[image]

until clicking another item or opening another legend item, when they revert to displaying the expression itself instead:
[image]

If I go back into a legend item and just backspace one or two characters, then it and all the other legend items revert back to showing the result. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2):

I think it could be because of the `(` followed by `[`. There is also a second `%` in the end of your formula. Expression should be surrounded by `[%` and `%]`.

First delete the last `%`.

Then delete the parenthesis around your expression and add the parenthesis in the expression formula. You can use the formula below as an example :

```
19th century 
[% '(' || 
(
   round(aggregate(layer:='Dwelling_Other',aggregate:='count', expression:="Cons_Yr", filter:=("Locality" IN ('Archies Creek') AND "Cons_Yr" >= 1801 AND "Cons_Yr" <= 1900))
   /
   aggregate(layer:='Dwelling_Other',aggregate:='count', expression:="Cons_Yr", filter:=("Locality" IN ('Archies Creek') AND "Cons_Yr" >= 1801))*100)
) 
|| ')'%]
```

*NB : The `||` will work only if your number have parentesis around or if it is converted to text with `to_string()`*

Comment: Thankyou Corentin. You are right, but those extra bits get appended by QGIS once I leave the expression window. I tried using the same expression in just a simple text label and there it is fine, so now I am inclined to think the issue is with using such an expression in the legend.